# Any cumulative distribution function on [0,1] is a convex combination of a continuous cdf and a discrete cdf?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Given that any increasing function on [0,1] is the sum of a step function and a continuous function, can we show that any cumulative distribution function on [0,1] is a convex combination of a continuous cdf and a discrete cdf?
It would follow that each Borel probability measure on [0,1] is the convex combination of prob measure with continuous density and a discrete probability measure.

Answer (score 1):

One counterexample is the [Cantor distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution), a famous distribution that's neither discrete nor continuous nor mixed. In fact, we call it a [singular distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_distribution).